# mongoose callback hell to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I would like to switch this callback to a promise but having a hard time because of the relation in my models

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  Campground.findById(req.params.id, (err, campground) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      redirect("/campgrounds");
    } else {
      Comment.create(req.body.comment, (err, comment) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          comment.save();
          campground.comments.push(comment);
          campground.save();
          res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
          console.log("comment created");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Tried doing my self but it errors out with "Cannot read property 'comments' of null"

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text;
  const newComment = new Comment({ text });
  Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((foundCampground) => {
      newComment
        .save()
        .then((comment) => {
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          comment.save();
          foundCampground.comments.push(comment);
          foundCampground.save();
        })
        .then(() => res.json("Comment added!"));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json(`Error ${err}`);
    });
});
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no record for `foundCampground` in your database. always test to see if there is a record returned from the database before pushing to the array. `findById` returns null if there is no record for a particular query

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text;
  const newComment = new Comment({ text });
  Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((foundCampground) => {
      newComment
        .save()
        .then((comment) => {
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          comment.save();
          if(foundCampground !== null){ //Added these line
          foundCampground.comments.push(comment);
          }
          foundCampground.save();
        })
        .then(() => res.json("Comment added!"));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json(`Error ${err}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: You'd probably want to check this before saving the comment, though

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Queries in mongoose are not promises. In order to change your queries into promises you have to use **.exec()** function.

### Example

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text;
  const newComment = new Comment({ text });
  Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec() // This line makes the trick
    .then((foundCampground) => {
      newComment
        .save()
        .then((comment) => {
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          comment.save();
          foundCampground.comments.push(comment);
          foundCampground.save();
        })
        .then(() => res.json("Comment added!"));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json(`Error ${err}`);
    });
});
```

### Reference

[Mongoose: Queries are not promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises)